# Build step failed with exception using build timeout plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have requirement to implement CI.Following are jenkins configuation details:

1. Jenkins server 32-bit (window 7)
2. Maven Integration plugin(version3.0)
3. Ant Plugin(Version 1.7)
4. Build Timeout(Version 1.19)
5. SQLPlus Script Runner( version 1.0.9)
6. Subversion Plug-in (Version 2.9)

I have following job configutaion:

1. Configure SVN Repository in Source Code Management step
2. On Build Environment ->Pre Steps -> using build timeout plugin->Sql script runner for oracle database.

[image: SQl Runner Configuartion with build timeout plugin]

When I executed the job i received following error but if i tried to excute Sql script runner without using build timeout it run smoothly :

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild cannot be cast to hudson.model.Build
    at hudson.plugins.build_timeout.BuildStepWithTimeout.perform(BuildStepWithTimeout.java:73)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:736)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:945)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:683)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:496)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1737)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Build step 'Run with timeout' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried build timeout with ant script same error message is coming.Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: What is build elapsed time?

Comment: Timeout minutes is configured in 3 min.